# Add date in Mysqldump when running cmd from Java and Shell

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, java-8, centos

I would like to append date in file name when taking backup using mysqldump. I am storing the command in properties file and running it via ProcessBuilder and shell script. I have tried multiple ways to add the date (BTW all the answers here were only if we run the command directly in linux)

`mysqldump -u <user> -p <database> | gzip > <backup>$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz`
Got the error: No table found for "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S"

`` mysqldump -u root -ppassword dbName --result-file=/opt/backup/`date -Iminutes`.dbName.sql ``
Got the error: unknow option -I

Is there a way around for this to add date in the command itself? I cannot append the date in java method or shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question whether you're running in a shell.  If so, try these three lines to generate your backup file.

```
 DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`
 FILENAME=backup${DATE}.sql.gz
 mysqldump -u user -p database | gzip > ${FILENAME}
```

Notice how you should surround the date command in the first line with backticks, not `${}`, to get its result into the DATE shell variable.

Comment: I tried running the command with the backticks as well:
mysqldump -u root -ppassword dbName --result-file=/opt//backup/``date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S``.dbname.sql

I got the error:  Couldn't find table: "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`.dbname.sql"

Comment: I cannot change the command in shell, i am storing this command in a file and then have to run it directly via shell script. So i was hoping to add the date and time when the command is getting executed